# rails generate ckeditor:install for rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, ckeditor, rails-generate

I'm trying to install and set up this gem - https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor, but when I follow the instructions and run:

```
rails generate ckeditor:install
```

I get an error because "rails generate" is a rails 3 command (I think?!).. so my question is, what is the equivalent rails 2 command to run this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ruby script/generate ckeditor:install
```

This should do it in Rails 2

Sven

Comment: Ah, I tried that before but I didn't work, it was infact
    "ruby script/generate ckeditor_install"
Thanks tho!